# How to fix 'undefined reference' when compiling in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile a C program linking two previously created object files but keep getting an 'undefined reference' error.

I'm using Visual Code to write the code and Ubuntu on Windows to compile using a makefile. The two C files, **task5.c** and **reverse.c** which have been made into object files both contain `#include reverse.h` statements which contains the prototypes for the functions in **reverse.c**.

**task5.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ctap.h"
#include "reverse.h"

TESTS {
    const char *a = "Family";
    char *b = reverse(a);

    //test 1
    ok(string_length(a) == string_length(b), "Strings are the same size");

    //test 2
    is("ylimaF", b, "Strings match");
}
```

**reverse.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "reverse.h"

char *reverse(const char *str) {
    //code
}

int string_length(const char *str) {
    //code
}
```

**reverse.h**

```
char *reverse(const char *str);
int string_length(const char *str);
```

**makefile**

```
linked:
    gcc -o linked task5.o reverse.o

task5.o
    gcc -c -o task5.o task5.c

reverse.o
    gcc -c -o reverse.o reverse.c
```

When I run the command `make linked` I expect it to be made and return nothing.

But when I run that command I get this error:

```
cc   task5.o   -o linked
task5.o: In function `ctap_tests':
task5.c:(.text+0x1abe): undefined reference to `reverse'
task5.c:(.text+0x1ace): undefined reference to `string_length'
task5.c:(.text+0x1adc): undefined reference to `string_length'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'linked' failed
make: *** [task5] Error 1
```

Comment: You have a makefile which links both object files. But you don't seem to be using it? Or using an old makefile? Because the output you show doesn't match the makefile you show.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix describes the topic (C++ centered, but probably generally also helpful for C).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What part doesn't match? If you're referring to the 'In function `ctap_tests':' ctap_tests is there because the macro TESTS{} expands to 'void ctap_tests(void)' according to VSCode when I hover over TESTS{} in task5.c.

Comment: Ah, I've just tried compiling it using 'gcc -o linked task5.o reverse.o' instead of make linked and it worked. I'm not sure why it would be using another make file but thanks for getting me to check it out, it's definitely something wrong with the make file.

Comment: Try using the `ls` command to list the files in the current directory. Do you have multiple "makefiles" (and remember that Linux filesystems are case-sensitive)? If there's only one, if you type it (with the `cat` command) is it the one you expect?

Comment: The ls command still only shows the one makefile as 'makefile.mk', when i use the cat command it is the exact same makefile as what I see in VSCode so I'm not sure what other makefile would be being referenced and why the output isn't the same.

Comment: Try to rename it `Makefile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this GNU `make` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Running), the GNU make program will try to use `GNUMakefile`, `makefile` or `Makefile`.

The `make` program will *not* try `makefile.mk`, which means that e.g. `make linked` will use no makefile and only the default rules.

You can solve this by either renaming your makefile as `Makefile` (the most common) or `makefile`; Or by using the `-f` option to specify the makefile

```
$ make -f makefile.mk linked
```

Comment: Thankyou! You were right, it was the way VSCode named the makefile when i saved it, I just rewrote it in notepad++ and saved it as just makefile (VSCode wouldn't let me) and it worked!